# Fine Grained access control for dynamodb does not work for LeadingKeys:${aws:username}

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, access-control

I'm just trying out a POC for my use-case so I'm still trying to understand a lot of new concepts.

I created a user with username adam123 and the dynamo db table has a partition key and a sort key of say username and some address. So one of the items include:

username: adam123
address: 123 street

I gave the user limited dynamodb access using fine grained control (used LeadingKeys condition) and specified LeadingKeys:${aws:username}. But it still says access denied.

I want to understand if I want a dynamic use-case for LeadingKeys, is there a limitation on using on userID, cognito credentials? Can I use say session tags or username

Comment: Can you show your permission policy and the DDB query?